# Телеграм бот. При нажатии на кнопки не реагируют на нажатия, обработчик нажатия на кнопки я прописал Пожалуйста, помогите

Tags: telegram-bot

## Телеграм бот

При нажатии на кнопки не реагируют на нажатия, обработчик нажатия на кнопки я прописал Пожалуйста, помогите.

```
import telebot

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

knight = ["Совсем недавно умер французский король Карл IV не оставив после себя законных наследников. Возможно, одним из них можешь быть, и ты! Здесь мы проверим твою честность, терпение, справедливость… И посмотрим достоин ли ты быть королем этих земель. Рыцарь, бесчестный язык и бесчестный ум впустую тратят наше время, а значит, впустую тратят нашу жизнь. Броня лжи выкована из мрака, она скрывает нас не только от других, но и от нашей собственной души. Честность – вот истинная добродетель. Скажи мне, рыцарь, только честно, сколько лет длилась столетняя война."]

greeting = ["Столетняя война – самая длинная в истории. На самом деле столетняя война является скорее чередой нескольких войн, между которыми были и вполне мирные времена, и временные затишья, которые затем снова сменялись пламенем войны. Приветствую тебя, рыцарь! Ты находишься на виртуальном полигоне Столетней войны."]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Старт":
        greeting_v = open('E:\Stoletnyaya_voyna_bot\Images\welcome.webp', 'rb')
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, greeting_v)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, greeting)
        knight_v = open('E:\Stoletnyaya_voyna_bot\Images\knight.webp', 'rb')
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, knight_v)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, knight)

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

        key_owan = types.InlineKeyboardButton('100', callback_data='v1n')
        keyboard.add(key_owan)
        key_otu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='110', callback_data='v1n')
        keyboard.add(key_otu)
        key_otri = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='116', callback_data='v1v')
        keyboard.add(key_otri)
        key_ozet = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='120', callback_data='v1n')
        keyboard.add(key_ozet)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери дату', reply_markup=keyboard)
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши Старт если хочешь начть")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback(call):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == "v1v":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Рыцарь, ты доказал, что ты честен. Ты готов вступить в бой. Выбирай битву, в которой ты хотел бы сразиться:  ")

                keyboard_wan = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                #Кнопки
**
                key_slas = types.InlineKeyboardButton('В морском сражении при Слейсе ', callback_data='v2v')
                key_kresi = types.InlineKeyboardButton('В знаменитой битве при Креси', callback_data='v2v')
                keyboard_wan.add(key_kresi, key_slas)
**
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Выбери сражение', reply_markup=keyboard_wan)
            elif call.data == "v1n":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Рыцарь, честность - не самая твоя сильная сторона. Тебе вспороли живот за не знание элементарных вещей. Ты умер")
                death1 = open('E:\Stoletnyaya_voyna_bot\Images\death.webp', 'rb')
                bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, death1)
    #Оброботчик нажатия
** 
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback(call):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == "v2v":**
**
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'На чьей стороне ты готов сразиться?')
                #Подготовка кнопок
                keyboard2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                #Кнопки
                key_angl_k = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Англия ', callback_data='v3v')
                keyboard2.add(key_angl_k)
                key_frans_k = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Франция ', callback_data='v3n')
                keyboard2.add(key_frans_k)
                #Вывод кнопок
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Выбери срадение', reply_markup=keyboard2)
```

Comment: Укажите конкретную проблему. Если решили указать на неё по номеру строки, то хоть как-то пронумеруйте, а ещё лучше с акцентируйте на неё внимание как-либо. Я не поленился вставить ваш код в IDE и у вас код из 52 строк!

Comment: Спасибо, я его изменил. Дело в том, что я первый раз делаю что-то подобное

Comment: Честно говоря, я не очень понимаю что там происходит. Попробуйте "keyboard_wan.add(key_kresi, key_slas)" разбить на keyboard_wan.add(key_kresi) и keyboard_wan.add(key_slas). Если у вас работают случаи с "v1n", то может быть поможет.   Так же проблема может быть в том, что вы добавляете кнопки к разным разметкам клавиатуры: keyboard_wan и keyboard.